# Get a list from a dict and save an element from that List Python

Tags: python, dictionary

The title is very explicit. i have a dict (very very big dict), and a it has this:

```
'orderItems': {
    'entries': [{
        'links': {
             'order': {
                'href': 'https: //api-latest.wdpro.xxxxx.com/booking-servicx/xxxxx/154301425212-3420290-4070919-6588782'
            }
```

so, `orderItems` is a dict, inside it has `entries` that is a list and inside it has`links`, what i need to get is the `href` inside `order`

i´m getting the list with: `orderlink = json_response["orderItems"]["entries"]`

but i´m not very sure how to go through the list to find the `href`. Maybe with `in`.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to get any of the hrefs, or the first one? Are there other non-link entries?

Comment: @tobias_k inside 'links' there is only one 'order' and i need that 'href'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access elements in a list, you have to use numeric indexes, or process all of them.

The best thing probaly is to use a for loop in there, that will guarantee you will iterate over  all entries on the list:

```
hrefs  = []
for entry in orderlink:
   hrefs.append(entry["links"]["order"]["href"])
```

that will give you a list with only the desired URLs

Comment: is it not `entry['links']['order']['href']`?

Comment: @gonkan - sure - but it looks like the O.P. found his way around it. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have that JSON structure I will use this code to solve your problem:

```
# Suppose that json_response is the whole dictionary
entry_list = json_response["orderItems"]["entries"]

# Now for each entry in the list, you need to get the "href" field
hrefs = []
for entry in entry_list:
    curr_href = entry["links"]["order"]["href"]
    hrefs.append(curr_href)
```

You need to pay attention to the dictionary structure in order to access to the field correctly. Before using this code, please pay read about dictionaries in the [Python3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).